# PHP - Centos OpenSSL error

Tags: php, httpd, openssl, centos6.5

i'm currently having a problem with OpenSSL on my Centos 6.5 Server.
it ran perfectly fine until sunday.
and i checked the error_log and i saw this error
in the log

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/openssl.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

i tried phpinfo();
and i found that openssl is enabled
i tried php -m

it returned

> [PHP Modules]
>
> - bz2
> - calendar
> - Core
> - ctype
> - curl
> - date
> - dom
> - ereg
> - exif
> - fileinfo
> - filter
> - ftp
> - gd
> - gettext
> - gmp
> - hash
> - iconv
> - interbase
> - json
> - libxml
> - mbstring
> - mcrypt
> - memcache
> - mysql
> - mysqli
> - openssl
> - pcntl
> - pcre
> - PDO
> - PDO_Firebird
> - pdo_mysql
> - pdo_sqlite
> - Phar
> - pspell
> - readline
> - Reflection
> - session
> - shmop
> - SimpleXML
> - snmp
> - sockets
> - SPL
> - sqlite3
> - standard
> - tokenizer
> - wddx
> - xml
> - xmlreader
> - xmlrpc
> - xmlwriter
> - xsl
> - zip
> - zlib

UPDATE

this is what i got from rpm -qa | grep php just like what [Mike](https://serverfault.com/users/23818/mike) Suggested

- php-php-gettext-1.0.11-3.el6.noarch
- php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
- php-interbase-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
- php-pdo-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-mysql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-snmp-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-gd-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-xml-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-pear-1.9.4-4.el6.noarch
- php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
- phpMyAdmin-3.5.8.2-1.el6.noarch
- php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-cli-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-devel-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-mbstring-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-xmlrpc-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
- php-pspell-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64

Comment: No such module is shipped by PHP in CentOS. It is compiled directly in, instead. Where did you get it?

Comment: i installed php using yum

Comment: What version? From what repository? You need to provide _as much information as possible_ here so that we don't have to spend all day dragging it out.

Comment: PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Aug  6 2014 05:54:27)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies this is what i got from php -v

Comment: run a `rpm -qa | grep php` and update your question with the answer

Comment: @Mike updated as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in a php.ini or alternative ini files you have an "extension=openssl.so" line which you need yo remove to get rid of that error.